# spacing inside label's border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

Friends,
i have created a UILabel with border (just like the image below).

I want to start my label after one/two lines left and then after finishing last line of label again one/two lines below.

Is there any way to get spacing inside label's border?

[image: This is the UILabel with border]

```
    UILabel *cmntBoxlbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 23, 250, 60)];
     cmntBoxlbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
     cmntBoxlbl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
     cmntBoxlbl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
      NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"  ",[[self.DtlArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"],@" "];
      cmntBoxlbl.text = text;

      cmntBoxlbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
      cmntBoxlbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
      [cmntBoxlbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

      CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cmntBoxlbl.font
                            constrainedToSize:cmntBoxlbl.frame.size
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

      CGRect newFrame = cmntBoxlbl.frame;
      newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
      cmntBoxlbl.frame = newFrame;
      cmntBoxlbl.numberOfLines = 0;
      [cmntBoxlbl sizeToFit];
      [cell addSubview:cmntBoxlbl];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make current label(commentLabel) color is white. create another label with same content and a little smaller size,place it inside the boarder.Make padding as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried this-

      NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@%@%@\n\n",@"  ",[[self.DtlArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"],@" "];
```

Comment: thanks rahul...its working for the first line space
But after the text,this is not working
I mean after last line there is no space below

Comment: I tried it & it works for me. Only the thing is at the end only one line is blank. Try giving more blank lines at below like-

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@%@%@\n\n\n",@"  ",[[self.DtlArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"],@" "];

Answer (score 0):

You may create a custom view and

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
      ......;
      [string drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:mode alignment:ali];
      ......;
}
```

hope that helps